# Having trouble creating a constantly changing number between 1-10 to appear on my site. Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a constantly changing number between 1-10 (refresh every 1.5 seconds or so) to appear on my site without a click event, Is this possible?

I've been using the `math.random` javascript function for the numbers. But I can't figure out how to do this "refreshing number" without using an onclick.

Can someone help me?

Comment: if you reload the page, the script will start running again, then you would need AJAX requests to update the number. Do you really want page refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: (assuming you want the number to appear in a div with id of "randomDiv"

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#randomDiv").text(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}, 1500);
```

Comment: Hi, What does 9 in Math.random(9) do? I was under the impression that Math.random doesn't take arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval function in javascript:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){

        //logic for generate random number and show it on the page

    }, 1000); //will be executing in every one second
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1  );
        }, 1000);
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply the randomly-generated number by 10, and round the decimals off. You will need to change the code inside the function so it outputs the result to somewhere in your document.

```
function randNumber() {
     var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1); 
   // Use rand somewhere in document
}

setInterval(randNumber, 1500); // Execute randNumber every 1.5 seconds
```

Comment: When will you use the returned value from the function randNumber?? :-P

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done by using setInterval and random no. generator. Here's one with flavored css.

```css
#result{
 color:#fff;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
background: #ffb76b; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffb76b 0%, #ffa73d 50%, #ff7c00 51%, #ff7f04 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffb76b 0%,#ffa73d 50%,#ff7c00 51%,#ff7f04 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffb76b', endColorstr='#ff7f04',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>

<script>

var intrvl = setInterval(numbFunction, 1500); //repeat function after 1.5 seconds(1500 ms)

function numbFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); //return a random no. between 1 to 10
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example I am changing random number in a label in every 1.5 second. To do this follow these steps:

**Step-1** I created a HTML label where my random number between 1-10 will be shown.

```
<label id="LblNumber"></label>
```

**Step-2** Then I created setInterval function which is calling a function ChangeNumber in every 1500 milliseconds(1.5 second). ChangeNumber function is generating random number betwwen 1-10 and set the label text with newly generated ramdom number.
    setInterval(function(){ChangeNumber(); }, 1500);

```
function ChangeNumber() {
   var newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random(9) * 10) + 1;
   $('#LblNumber').text(newNumber);
}
```

[See Fiddler Here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/8y9ancpp/)

Hope this help!!